# How does global variable in package body work for multiple users

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have written a program in which SQL queries & query ID is saved in a table. User will select the query ID and program will generate its output to specified UNIX directory. 

Right now I am saving the query in global variable of package body after fetching it from the table.

My concern is that when multiple users will run the program at same time, will my global variable (which is storing the SQL query) will update accordingly?

for example:

```
    create or replace package test
    is
    global_sql varchar2(40000);

       procedure get_sql(p_sql_id number)
        is 
       begin

         select sql into global_sql from query_table where sql_id = p_sql_id;
         //more code     
       end;

    end;
```

now when multiple users run this program at the same time for different sql_id, will my global_sql will be different for all users accordingly?

Comment: Do you mean the *results* of a query are stored in a global variable?

Comment: @BobC I have updated the question. I hope question is clear now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you mean package variables? 
In that case any user in any different connection will get his own value in his own copy of variable. All this values will be stay in UGA(user global area).

For example i create package without body to hold one variable:

```
connect test/test

create or replace package test_var is 
   v_sql_text varchar2(4000); 
end test_var;
/

exec test_var.v_sql_text := 'FIRST_QUERY:select * from dual';
```

open another session

```
connect test/test
set serveroutput on 

exec dbms_output.put_line( test_var.v_sql_text); 

/*result is empty*/

exec test_var.v_sql_text := 'TEXT_QUERY:select * from all_tables'; 

exec dbms_output.put_line( test_var.v_sql_text); 

-- 
TEXT_QUERY:select * from all_tables
```

return to the first session

```
exec dbms_output.put_line( test_var.v_sql_text); 

-- 
FIRST_QUERY:select * from dual
```

Comment: Just to add to this answer, it's not per user, it's per database session. That means you need to be careful if you're using connection pooling, as you'd most likely need to reset the value of the global variable(s) each time you started off a new run through the code, since you can't rely on the session being closed to reset the package state.